# Eclipse CDT building and launching application for Docker Container

Tags: eclipse, docker, containers, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Photon CDT on Windows 10, with all Docker integration Prerequisite already installed.
I have one ubuntu docker image which is running on same machine.
I can check running ubuntu container from Docker Explorer view of Eclipse.
Now I am facing problem in building and launching Hello World C++ simple application inside docker.
When I change my build settings and uncheck build inside container, then application gets built for local environment but when I select run inside container, No binary is formed..

Please help me figuring this out, I am following all steps as defined in latest eclipsecon. Not sure what's wrong.
Please if any one knows about this problem, try to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No error, its just out file is not getting generated

Comment: Does you docker image contain gcc? It seems eclipse does not report an error if there is no compiler available. I tried the gcc image and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The current (and older) release of **Eclipse CDT (2018-09) does not print an error if the command in the docker container fails with command not found**, see [bug 529656](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529656). A fix will be included in the  December release (2018-12).

The official [ubuntu docker image](https://store.docker.com/images/ubuntu) does not include `make` and `g++`. Therefore, the build will silently fail. Instead of the ubuntu image, you could use the [gcc](https://store.docker.com/images/gcc) image.